# OpenMAX DL (development layer) support in android

Tags: android, openmax, opencore

Is it possible to use OpenMAX DL library in android? AFAIK android 2.2 uses OpenCore that probably doesn't implement this part of OpenMAX standard. Few months ago VisualOn joined OHA and their VOME fully implements OpenMAX. Does anyone know if VOME is now part of android 2.3?
If so is there any example how to use it? I am especially interested in using optimized FFT function.